# RESTfully request sub-parts of a representation be of a certain content-type

Tags: http, rest, content-type

I am requesting (via `Accept: application/json`) that an API I'm designing respond as JSON. However, I want the values within that JSON to be specified to conform to `text/plain` or `text/html` depending on the capabilities of the client.

What is the RESTful best practice for a "sub-type"? How would this work if I formally switched to HAL as the top-level container?

#### Accept: application/json+text/plain

```
{
  "value": "Hello World"
}
```

#### Accept: application/json+text/html

```
{
  "value": "<h2>Hello World</h2>"
}
```

Comment: "RESTful" has nothing to do with this question. You just specify the `Accept:` header using the types you can accept. I'd be leary of adding non-standard suffixes like `application/json+txt/html` unless you know the server specifically offers them. The available content-types is something that should be clearly documented by any quality API.

Comment: Quite right, I could just as easily say HTTP. I am designing the API, and trying to find the closest to a standard practice for clients to communicate with the service on this topic. `application/json+txt/html` is one of the several very awkward solutions I've come up with, but I thought it was illustrative.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a parameter in your Accept: header? See for example how the profile parameter is defined for JSON-LD http://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld-syntax/#application-ld-json. So for example your accept header would be
`application/json; profile="http://mysite.org/json-type/html"`

Also bear in mind that X- fields as defined in the  RFC 1341 are deprecated: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648

Comment: +1 And thanks for the note on the `x-` deprecation. I'm 5 months late to the part on that one! Deleting my answer.

Comment: This is a more formal take on where I was starting to trend. I've tried some cross-pollination with the HAL discussion list to see how this matches up. I'd like to avoid a hybrid of json-ld/HAL/json. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/hal-discuss/HJAPsavOvPA/rPKv3-4yZyYJ